# SpringData findAll is processing all database tables and not the one requested

Tags: spring, spring-data, eclipselink, spring-data-jpa

I am new to SpringData and I am not getting what is happening here. I have created an Interface that extends PagingAndSortingRepository and overrided the findAll() method like this:

```
@Override
@Query
List<MyEntity> findAll();
```

I am calling this method in my service, but it is making my app to throw an exception `Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError` because that method is reading through the entire database, not only from `MyEntity`table in database. Any idea?

Comment: Turn on logging for EclipseLink and show your entity.  It could be a complex object graph with relationships eagerly fetched is forcing the provider to bring in all referenced entities in your object model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem is in the configuration of EclipseLink. In persistence.xml I added this row `<shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>` and now it works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

no need to override getall() method.in your service autowired that dao or repository class and using this you can directly call the findall() method.
in the case you want to write your custom method apart from what given by spring data jpa then we use the @Query to write custom query.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I was asking something else :)

Answer (score 0):

```
No Need to Override. What i have done is i have created a repository i.e  
FavoriteRepository which is extending JpaRepository and i have mentioned the 
dbmodel name (Favorite)

like this JpaRepository<Favorite, Long> // Here Favorite is my model name 
and Long is the type of primary key mentioned in db model Favorite as @Id 

@Repository
public interface FavoriteRepository extends JpaRepository<Favorite, Long>{

}

Now you can use method findOne or findAll. As these methods are present in  
Jparepository.Hope so it will help

If you want to add new method then use @Query with JpQL
@Query(value = "select f from Favorite f where  f.userId=:userId ")
public List<Favorite> getFavoritesForUser(@Param("userId") String userId);
```